# numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1?

Tags: python, axis, conv-neural-network

```
    def prepare_data_cnn(self):
        assert self.args.data_mode == 'sum', \
                'Use [-m sum] for training CNN'

        self.train_X = tf.keras.utils.normalize(self.train_X, axis=1)
        self.val_X = tf.keras.utils.normalize(self.val_X, axis=1)
        self.test_X = tf.keras.utils.normalize(self.test_X, axis=1)
```

With this code I get the following error.

(I don't get it wrong if I put 0 as axis value but I don't think I'm doing the right thing)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "drunk_detector\__main__.py", line 810, in <module>
    dd.predict();
  File "drunk_detector\__main__.py", line 229, in predict
    self.test_best_model()
  File "drunk_detector\__main__.py", line 542, in test_best_model
    self.prepare_data_cnn()
  File "drunk_detector\__main__.py", line 383, in prepare_data_cnn
    self.train_X = tf.keras.utils.normalize(self.train_X, axis=1)
  File "C:\Users\Acer 729465\Desktop\TESI\drunk-detection-CNN-master\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\np_utils.py", line 67, in normalize
    l2 = np.atleast_1d(np.linalg.norm(x, order, axis))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in norm
  File "C:\Users\Acer 729465\Desktop\TESI\drunk-detection-CNN-master\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 2507, in norm
    return sqrt(add.reduce(s, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims))
numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Comment: `self.train_X` only has one dimension

Comment: @Andrew so are you saying i am right to put axis = 0?

Comment: it depends a little on what that keras function is expecting as an input. If your data only has a single axis, then you can ignore that argument completely, in most cases. There's a possibility that your data needs an additional axis, in which case you can use `reshape(-1, 1)` or `[np.newaxis, :]`

Comment: @Andrew
```self.train_X = tf.keras.utils.normalize(self.train_X[np.newaxis, :], axis=1)```
do it